# Java class keyword different uses?

Tags: java, eclipse

A ***ClassName***.***class*** returns the *Class* object for that particular class. That said and understood, I can't really grasp what the keyword does when used directly in a method.., then, if we write ***class*** and follow it immediately with a dot, the list that appears seems to include all that's in scope there, i.e. local variables of the method, other methods and variables(depending on whether the method is static or not), method itself, and class itself..

Coming from its first stated function above, I find myself at odds with this one: I can't tell what it's exactly doing.. way I see it, it's the same word, expect same function at heart, but that doesn't seem to be the case here

Blurry.. I know, but any insight into it is appreciated. Thx.

Comment: "if we write _class_ and follow it immediately with a dot, the list that appears ..." <-- What are you talking about?

Comment: I think you can use an IDE, repeat that and post a Screenshot so we can figure out what are you talking about

Comment: In Eclipse, inside a method, write class. and you'll get a list of suggestions for what might follow

Comment: @Searcherer Your question does not even mention Eclipse.

Comment: "if we write class and follow it immediately with a dot, the list that appears seems to include all that's in scope there" <- If youare using eclipse you can get the same behaviour by just typing a dot. Or even any keyword and a dot. typing "else." will get you the same menu. Its just a weirdness in eclipse and has nothing to do with the class keyword. It also doesn't mean that the resulting code will be valid.

Comment: I didn't mention Eclipse cuz I didn't think it'd make dif. I didn't know that..! So the function of class is returning the Class object..? Just that, right?

Comment: I really can't understand why some people just haste to down-vote a question at a first impression.. I'm relatively new to Java, and I didn't notice it was an IDE thing, and u don't usually (nor r u supposed to) back it up to "weirdness in eclipse".. . Whatever, Thx. anyway.. .

Comment: You seem resentful that people​ answered your question. "Thx [sic] anyway"? Anyway, the `class` literal is explained in the documentation, which I recommend reading generally. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2 Read the Fine Manual!

Comment: "You seem resentful that people​ answered your question"  - that doesn't even deserve to be dignified with a comment. For all OTHERS who answered above, please know your answers are most appreciated. It was the down-voting that I felt bad about, not the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get similar behaviour from Netbeans:

[image: Screenshot from Netbeans]

However, these are somewhat bogus suggestions.

`class.emptyList()`, despite being a suggestion, will not compile. This is probably a peculiarity of the way suggestions are computed. If there's a way to get legal code out of these suggestions, I can't think of it.

Note that you get the same suggestions if you just hit `CTRL+enter` (or whatever keys you have bound to suggestions) on an empty statement.

Usually there are only two circumstances to use the word `class`:

1. When defining a class, for example `public class MyClass { ... }`
2. With a dot, after a class name, to get the Class object for a type - `Class<Person> clazz = Nurse.class`

Sometimes you feel you'd like to have a variable called `class`, but it's a reserved word, so you can't. It's quite common to see variables called `clazz` for that reason.

Comment: Thanks, Slim. I understand now.